# MySQL select random 10 rows from 5

Tags: mysql

I need to take 10 rows from table. It has to be random but in that table I have only 5 rows.
And so if I select:

```
SELECT * FROM `names` order by rand() limit 10
```

But this query returns me only 5.

How to get five more with repeat?

Comment: if there are 5 rows in table then definitely result will be 5 only

Comment: ok, but is there anything I can do to get all 10?

Comment: Is this in a stored proc or just ad-hoc? If it's in a proc you can use the number of rows in your table to generate a statement that will be a union if the number of records is less than 10.  Not sure how you can neatly do it in an ad-hoc fashion and make it dynamic.

Comment: it is ad-hoc not stored proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT m.* FROM `names` m,`names` n  order by rand() limit 10

This may be what you wanted

Comment: This is a neat solution and works for any number of records above 3.  Perhaps you could put more explanation of how it works for the OP?

Comment: This cross product will return m*n number of rows. In our case, the total number of rows is (m*m). Hence, as stated by Stephe it works for any number of records above 3.

Comment: thanks it works very well, but how fast is this query? I notice it is slower?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
SELECT * FROM names 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM names 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```